# SVN---Add current directory (.) to changelist

Tags: svn, svnignore, changelist, working-directory

I created a `.svnignore` file and then set it with the command `$ svn propset svn:ignore -R -F .svnignore .`. Now my current directory, `.`, and another subdirectory, `figures`, are shown as modified.

```
$ svn status 
 M      .
 M      figures
```

When I try adding these two directories to a changelist, it fails. How do I add these two directories to a changelist?

```
$ svn changelist 'Pink Fairy Armadillo' . figures
Skipped '.'
Skipped 'figures'
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> How do I add these two directories to a changelist?

You can't. From the [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.changelists.html):

> **Changelist Limitations**
>
> Changelists can be assigned only to files—Subversion doesn't currently support the use of changelists with directories.

Comment: As ridiculous as it may sound I read the changelist section a few days ago but judging from today my brain somehow didn't pick up that part.

Comment: What to do in case of "directory is not under version control and is not part of the commit, yet its child is part of the commit."?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was true last March, but you can recursively add all the files in a directory using this command

```
svn changelist my_changelist --recursive folder_name
```

It does add EVERYTHING, and not just modified files, but your commit should only hit the modified stuff anyway, and you can use the same --recursive flag to remove a folder from the changelist - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905000/how-do-i-remove-an-existing-changelist-from-svn#answer-15073860)

```
svn changelist --remove --recursive folder_name
```

Comment: This doesn't add the directory itself to the changelist, which is what the OP asked about. And directories still can't be added to changelists in SVN 1.8 (the latest) according to the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.changelists.html#svn.advanced.changelists.limitations).

Comment: I've edited my comment to attempt to be slightly more clear about the hopefully helpful piece of advice I added on a whim to an already answered year old question. You could just edit it next time, if you find it lacking....

Answer (score -4):

But you can use:

```
svn changelist 'Pink Fairy Armadillo' path_to_dir/*
```

Should achieve the same thing.

Comment: this does not add the directory to the changelist